# UK visa refused because the immigration officer has misinterpreted my documents. How do I appeal his decision?

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, visa-refusals, paperwork, standard-visitor-visas

I am a Research Scholar and an Indian National and had applied for a Standard Visitor Visa (Academic Visitor upto 6 months) to the UK. I was invited by a faculty at King's College London (KCL) to informally interact with him on a topic of discussion. This is purely an informal academic visit and not an internship. For this I had given an invitation letter from him stating clearly the same and also other supporting documents.

The ECO at SHEFO got King's College confused with University College London (UCL) and, hence, could not find any supporting documents from the ones I had submitted regarding UCL. So, my visa was refused. How do I go about overturning this decision? I have mailed them and also tried calling them but got no response.

I'm due to leave on May 21, 2017. I haven't yet cancelled my flight bookings and reservations. Here's a scan of my refusal letter.

[image: Refusal Letter]

Comment: Do you have adverse immigration history? Curious because it was mentioned explicitly that your immigration history was considered although it was not mentioned in the exact reason for refusing.

Comment: Is it possible your supporting documents were lost? Were they returned to you? Has been known to happen. The refusal was also quite broad, broader than we normally see here which typically will reference the specific subsection e.g v4.2(a) or v4.5(c)

Comment: This is my first visit abroad. Supporting documents are scanned and uploaded. They were not sent in the first place. They were scanned infront of me at Vfs.

Comment: @Phantom the "immigration history" text is standard, and it doesn't preclude the meaning "I have considered the fact that you have never before been to the UK," which is apparently the case here.

Comment: I redacted your info from the refusal. Why does the ECO say that the  academic at KCL is not aware of your visit  or expecting you? Do you have reason to believe that he was contacted to confirm what you had provided (whether it was KCL or UCL)? Have you contacted him?

Comment: Maybe you could upload the redacted documents you sent to support your invitation.

Comment: @MarkMayo absent the supporting documents that OP says are the cause of the refusal, IMO there is no way to adequately respond and think it should be closed as unclear. OP has not returned to the site since 21 May (and may not).

Comment: missing the point here a bit maybe but- hotel in coventry for a visit to a London university? That seems odd.

Comment: @theotherone King's College has a campus in Coventry.

Answer (score 3):

This answer may be moot since the deadlines have already passed however what I learned from [Gayot Fow](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow) (to whom thanks) is that an indirect and usually quicker way of getting a case like yours heard exists (particularly if you believe it is mainly due to the mix-up of the universities and your application is otherwise strong): it's called a **fresh application**; if you had included documentation clarifying the mix-up, you would have had great chances for success.[image]

Go to: [Apply for a UK visa](https://visas-immigration.service.gov.uk/product/uk-visit-visa)
 on the UK.GOV website and start.